# Weird Variable / Mysql Issue

Tags: php, mysql, database, variables

I just don't know what to do, and don't know how to search about this weird problem. Here is is:

All the connection on the page are working correctly, just in case:

I Have this code to update an Email on the Database

```
$fUsername = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['user']);
$fPassword = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['senha']);
$fEmail = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['fEmail']);

$sql = "UPDATE usuario SET email='$fEmail ' WHERE username = '$fUsername' and senha = '$fPassword'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
```

Now, the Problem:

This query is not Updating the "Email" field on the BD. It just makes the field empty.

If I echo the $sql var, I get this:
  UPDATE usuario SET email='teste@gmail.com ' WHERE username = 'teste1' and senha = 'e10adc3949ba59abbe56e057f20f883e'

If I ran manually this query on the mySQL, it updates the field like I want.

If I manually pass a value to the $fEmail var (***$fEmail = "teste@gmail.com"***). It works just fine.

The only way that don't work is when I take the value from the **Form**.

Does anyone have the solution for this? D:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `$_GET` for the username and password, and `$_POST` for the email. Check your `form` actual submit method, and fix the relevant data fetching.

Comment: My form Submit methods is POST.

I use get due the Frinedly URLs of the site:
http://christinagrimmiebr.com/enviaemail/teste1/e10adc3949ba59abbe56e057f20f883e/

So, the first GET gets the "teste1", and the second gets the HASH.

And via POST, I get the email.

Is this possible / allowed?

Comment: are you certain about that? and check your `input` `name` attribute and verify it is actually `fEmail`. Other than that, nothing else may interfere with the results.

Make sure you don't have any typos in the `name` attribute.

Comment: @FilipeVersehgi: let me know if it didn't fix it; if so, you may need to provide more code (of the HTML form, and anything before the relevant PHP code) for us to help any further. Good luck!

Comment: Hey! It worked!

I parsed the form Email field with JQuery and redirected the page to a friendly URL, then retrived all the values via GET ("http://somesite.com/enviaemail/teste1/e10adc3949ba59abbe56e057f20f83e/test@test.com.br/") and worked like a charm.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You should use `$_GET['fEmail']` if the form data is being sent via GET.  `$_POST['fEmail']` is not defined in that case, which would explain the behavior you're seeing.